# Sql query to generate event sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `event` in below format.

```
user_id   event_name  sequence_number
   1        open         1
   1        export       3
   1        import       2
   1        close        5
   1        publish      4
   2        close        3
   2        open         1
   2        import       2
```

Here `sequence_number` tells the order in which that event is used. for example event with sequence_number `2` is used before the event with sequence_number `1` for that particular user.

With the help of above table `event`,  I have to create another table called 
`event_sequence` which will show the sequence of event for each user.
our output table will look like :

```
user_id   event_order
  1       open->import->export->publish->close
  2       open->import->close
```

I am using postgresql.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_agg()`:

```
select e.user_id,
       string_agg(e.event_name, '->' order by sequence_number) as events
from event e
group by e.user_id;
```